# How long does a smooth function maintain its "size"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth function
on an open interval $I$. Let $x_{0}\in I$ and suppose that

1)  $f(x_{0})=0$

2) $|f^{(i)}(x_{0})|\sim N$ for some large $N$
for all $i\geq 1$
( meaning that all derivatives of $f$ are of size about $N$ at $x_{0}$; more precisely, there exist two constants $c_{1},c_{2}>0$  such that
$$c_{1}N\leq |f^{(i)}(x_{0})|\leq c_{2}N $$
for all $i\geq 1$.

Question:

How long can any of these derivatives stay of size $N$ ?

I mean what is the largest $\delta$ such that, say, $|f^{\prime}(x)|\sim N$ on $]x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta[$ ?

For simplicity, assume $|f^{(i)}(x_{0})|=1$
for all $i\geq 1$. Find the largest $\delta$
such that 
$|f^{\prime}(x)|\geq \frac{1}{2}$ on $]x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta[$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a non negative $C^\infty$ function with compact support on $[-1,1]$ and such that $\phi(x)=1$ if $|x|\le1/2$. Given $\epsilon>0$ let
$$
f_\epsilon(x)=(e^x-1)\phi(x/\epsilon).
$$
Then $f_\epsilon(x)=e^x-1$ if $|x|\le\epsilon/2$, $f_\epsilon(0)=0$ and $f^{(i)}(0)=1$ for all $i\ge1$. But $f$ and all its derivatives are equal to $0$ when $x=\pm\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we see that there is no $\delta>0$ depending only of the values of the derivatives of $f$ at $x=0$ such that $|f'(x)|\ge1/2$ on $(-\delta,\delta)$.